# BEGINWITH predicate not working when i try to pass second character

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsarray, nspredicate

I am trying to make suggestions for textfield. Below is my code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSLog(@"String output: %@", string);
    NSString *stringToSearch = string;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH %@",stringToSearch]; // if you need case sensitive search avoid '[c]' in the predicate

    // NSLog(@"Predicate has some ?: %i", [predicate ])
    selectedOne = [colorAutocompleteArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


    NSLog(@"count of selected: %lu",(unsigned long)[selectedOne count]);

    NSLog(@"Select Array: %@", selectedOne);

    NSLog(@"Text entered: %@", textField.text);

    tableView.hidden = NO;
    [tableView reloadData];


    return true;

}
```

When i enter first alphabet it works fine but as soon as i enter second one it returns nothing. Whereas, i tried predicate with 'contains' keyword it works fine but the list of suggestion is to big because it checks each and every entery of array containing any of the letter. So i want something like hasPrefix method so i tried this but it never returns any thing on more than one entries. Each of yours comment would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
NSString *stringToSearch = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:string];
```

because "**string**" returns only **last char** you are entering, so **between** should not work

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this method returns one character at a time not all the characters you are entering.

```
NSLog(@"String output: %@", string);
NSString *stringToSearch = string;
```

Check this and take the whole string of textField .

Hope this will help You.